# How to install tar.gz file?

Tags: 14.04, tar

I downloaded Apache httpd-2.4.18.tar.gz file.
But I don't know how to install that one?!

Comment: And you're not installing Apache from repositories because?

Answer (score 1):

It's more complicated to install a package from source. Maybe it would be easier to install it directly by using `apt-get install apache2`

Otherwise with your downloaded file, you can install it too...

Extract the file

```
gzip -d httpd-NN.tar.gz
tar xvf httpd-NN.tar
```

Go on your extracted folder

```
cd httpd-NN
```

Configure

```
./configure --prefix=PREFIX
```

Compile the package

```
make
```

Install it

```
make install
```